# configuring MSMQ to route messages from one queue to another queue (target)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, msmq

My requirement is as follows:

I need to write messages to a  queue on one machine-1 which should be routed in to another queue on another machine-2 (within the network) by MSMQ automatically.

1. Is this possible?
2. Can this be done WITHOUT a program polling for the presence of messages and moving the messages to machine-2 programatically?
3. For  MSMQ to automatically take care of this, what do we need to configure on machine-1?

Please let me know!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"1.Is this possible?"
No.

MSMQ delivers messages to a queue. That's it.
To route a message from one queue to another, you are effectively reading the message and writing a copy to the new destination.